# GTX 970 and i7 4790k for 1080p60 while recording

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards

I have a laptop with gtx960m and i7-3610qm(6M Cache, up to 3.30 GHz). I can play with it at 720p30 on medium settings and can't record my games (that's the most important point) more than 480p30.

I'm looking for a build with which i can play on 1080p60 on average **while recording** my games at the same definition/frame rate.

I prefer to not use sli, and I'm going to buy a i7-4790k (8M Cache, up to 4.40 GHz).

My requirements for a graphics card are:

1. able to render 1080p60 in the latest games in ultra settings
2. able to render 1080p60 in last games while recording

I have been looking at the gtx970, but I am not sure if it fits the requirements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is a technical support request, which is not in the scope of Hardware Recommendations.

Comment: I have edited your question to prevent it from being closed. If I changed it too much, you may rollback my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question about recording, recent NVidia cards have a feature called ShadowPlay that can record games using a chip in the card independently of the CPU and the rest of the GPU, meaning next to no performance impact on games and computer usage. ShadowPlay is capable of both recording and streaming in 1080P at 60 FPS.

The limiting factor for recording on a 970 is more likely to be your HDD or SSD. It's strongly recommended to record to a second HDD, apart from the disk where Windows and the game is installed, to avoid the disk from being overloaded.

However, in response to whether the 970 is good enough; the GTX 1060 will be released soon (sources say the 14th of July) which will most likely offer performance improvements over the 970. I strongly recommend waiting until then before making a decision and buying the 970.

As to whether the 970 is powerful enough to run the latest games at ultra settings, that's a matter of the game. Games like The Witcher 3 are very graphically intensive and can't be run with high FPS on the 970.

Without knowing the specific games you're interested in playing, it's best to look up user experiences for the card and game you're interested in.

Edit: [This article says the GTX 1060 will rival the performance of a 980](http://videocardz.com/61753/nvidia-geforce-gtx-1060-specifications-leaked-faster-than-rx-480), so again, I strongly recommend waiting.

Comment: Note: Recording with ShadowPlay is not as stressing for your drive as other software would be, because it "only" writes up to 50MBit/s onto the drive which is less than 10MB/s and shouldn't impact _anything_ too much. It gets better if you go lower on quality (given that Youtube only gives you like 10-20 MBit/s anyways).